# Converting a function wrapper to std::function

Tags: c++, function, stl, c++14, std-function

My problem is that I have a function wrapper that contains an std::function inside. What i want to accomplish, is to be able to assign it to std::function - like that:

```
std::function a = mywrapper;
```

It works, but it loses information about emptiness in the process - even if std::function inside my wrapper class is empty, the newly created function a will not preserve this information - it cannot be casted to bool.

If my wrapper contains a nullptr (empty) std::function, the function a, after assignment, will say that it is non-empty; i.e. it will bool-cast to true.

Is there a way to remedy this behavior?

```
FunctionWrapper<void()> wrapper;
std::function<void()> std;
std = wrapper;
std::cout << std::boolalpha << bool(std) << std::endl;
```

This will resolve to true. And it should resolve to false.

Here is the header of FunctionWrapper class:

```
template < class >
class FunctionWrapper;

template<class R, class... ArgTypes>
class FunctionWrapper<R(ArgTypes...)>
{
private:
    std::function<R(ArgTypes...)> func = nullptr;

public:
    FunctionWrapper() = default;
    FunctionWrapper(const FunctionWrapper&) = default;
    FunctionWrapper(FunctionWrapper&&) = default;
    FunctionWrapper(const boost::function<R(ArgTypes...)>&);
    FunctionWrapper(boost::function<R(ArgTypes...)>&&);
    template<class F> FunctionWrapper(F);

    FunctionWrapper& operator=(const FunctionWrapper&) = default;
    FunctionWrapper& operator=(FunctionWrapper&&) = default;
    FunctionWrapper& operator=(boost::function<R(ArgTypes...)>&);
    FunctionWrapper& operator=(boost::function<R(ArgTypes...)>&&);
    template<class F> FunctionWrapper& operator=(F&&);

    ~FunctionWrapper() = default;

    //R operator()(ArgTypes...);

    operator std::function<R(ArgTypes...)>();
    operator boost::function<R(ArgTypes...)>();
    explicit operator bool();

};
```

Comment: Show us the body of the constructor or conversion operator `std::function` uses.

Comment: template<class R, class... ArgTypes>
    FunctionWrapper<R(ArgTypes...)>::operator std::function<R(ArgTypes...)>()
    {
     return func;
    }

Comment: Your operator overload is responsible for returning an unassigned `std::function`, instead of wrapping itself, if the wrapped function is not assigned.

Comment: Are you _sure_ that method is called?

Comment: Can we get a [mcve]?

Comment: @Sombrero Chicken No, it's not and thats the problem. std::function sees FunctionWrapper as a callable type and doesn't convert it.

Comment: Then explicitily cast the wrapper to a function first, or don't allow `std::function` to see `operator()`.

Comment: @SombreroChicken this is a solution, but FunctionWrapper is meant to work with other std::function object without explicit casting. Is there any way to make it this way?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is possible, short of language change with how assignment works.

When you write `std = wrapper`, that is syntax sugar for `std.operator=(wrapper)`. We're really invoking that function. It's not like initialization, where we also consider conversion functions at a more top-level<sup>†</sup>. So basically, we have our [`function::operator=`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function/operator%3D) options:

```
function& operator=( const function& other );                             // #1
function& operator=( function&& other );                                  // #2
function& operator=( std::nullptr_t );                                    // #3
template< class F >  function& operator=( F&& f );                        // #4
template< class F >  function& operator=( std::reference_wrapper<F> f );  // #5
```

`#3` and `#5` aren't viable, `#4` is by way of you having an appropriate `operator()` and `#1` and `#2` both are, both for the same reason and also the existence of your conversion function. But `#4` is an Exact Match whereas neither `#1` nor `#2` are, so it wins. Full stop.

The only way to get `#2` to be preferred to `#4` (what you really want) is to make `#4` not a candidate. But the only way to make `#4` not a candidate is to make `wrapper` not invocable. Which makes it... not a wrapper at all.

So you're basically out of luck here.

---

<sup>†</sup> Note that `std::function<void()> std = wrapper;` does what you want.